# data series that restarts across years

Tags: regression, time-series

I have a data series that looks like this:

```
Index   Date  Week     Y    X1      X2
1   1/1/1999    1      1    0.17    0.70
2   1/8/1999    2      2    0.14    0.32
3   1/15/1999   3      3    0.88    0.93
4   1/22/1999   4      4    0.33    0.49
5   1/29/1999   5      5    0.81    0.04
6   1/1/2000    1      6    0.35    0.26
7   1/8/2000    2      7    0.29    0.65
8   1/15/2000   3      8    0.39    0.46
9   1/22/2000   4      9    0.56    0.68
10  1/29/2000   5     10    0.90    0.82
{cont}
```

The data is continuous inside a year but them jumps from one year to the next. No values from `1999` have any impact on the values from `2000`. I would google this (seems like a basic question) but I don't even know what a series like this would be called!

Thanks!

Comment: The time series is sampled irregularly, but that's probably not sufficiently descriptive. You could model each year as its own separate, very short series, but probably there is some information you can and should share across years (the assertion that "no values from 1999 have *any* impact on the values from 2000" is probably too strong). For example, maybe the average `X1` level or growth rate can be assumed to be the same across years or to come from a specified distribution (in a hierarchical  model).

Comment: Do you know what this sort of series is called? I remember finding, but now have completely forgotten. It's similar to segmented, but not quite..